# Erratic alignment inside table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have got the following two-column `longtable` for items in my CV:

```
\begin{longtable}{ r l }
...
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Now the problem is: The second column containing the job descriptions is aligned quite fine, whereas the first column does not respect its right alignment although it only contains simple text (the dates) generated by some `\ifstrequal` commands to allow for special cases like (.. - present).

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xifthen} % provides \ifthenelse and \isempty
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable} 

\geometry{a4paper} 
\geometry{margin=2cm} 
\pagestyle{empty} 

\providecommand*{\cvitem}[4][]{
    \ifstrequal{#3}{-}{#2 – present}{
            \ifstrequal{#2}{#3}{#2}{
                #2 – #3
            }
    } & \parbox[t]{12.3cm}{ \raggedright
                \textbf{#4} 
                    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{  \\ #1 } % Only output second line if optional parameter given
            \\[0.5cm] }  \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ r l }
    \cvitem[foobar]{08/2011}{-}{foobar}
    \cvitem[foobarfooba]{04/2008}{08/2011}{foobar}
    \cvitem[foobar]{09/2006}{08/2007}{foobar}
    \cvitem[foobar]{08/2005}{08/2005}{foobar}
    \cvitem[foobar]{03/2005}{03/2005}{foobar}
    \cvitem[foobar]{05/2004}{05/2004}{foobar}
    \cvitem[foobar]{03/2004}{12/2005}{foobar}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  In this case it probably has something to do with how your using `\ifstrequal`.

Comment: Not the cause but I wouldn't use proportional figures for the dates. Your _1_ is clearly narrower than the other figures. It ain't look right boie.

Comment: You should always post _complete_ documents that can be run it's very hard to help given no information. Firstly have you run latex a few times (longtable does not line up on the first time) otherwise the most likely cause is spurious space characters and the traditional cause of those is missing `%` at ends of lines in macro definitions. But impossible to say.

Comment: Thanks for all your helpful comments so far. Here is my MWE showing the problem: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/133332/MWE.tex


Please note: As I am using a special font installed on my system, I use XeTeX and the fontspec package. Removed it in the MWE, ran with LaTeX and the problem persists, so it seems to have nothing to do with which font is used.

@DavidCarlisle: I've run latex dozens of times, no change in the output.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the text directly (I did it in this case) Note unrelated to the alignment your use of – to get an n-dash is non standard and won't work in general, the standard markup for that is --

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Regarding the n-dash: – is just like any other Unicode character, so what does it have to do with being non standard if I use Unicode encoding and simply insert such characters as plain text?

Comment: nothing except your MWE didn't specify [utf8]{inputenc} so will only work out of the box with xetex or luatex, which was what I was trying to say. since classic tex (and pdftex) are far from being unicode aware.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: (completely off-topic, sorry everyone) Good to see you back!

Comment: @Jake Thanks. I've been lurking all the time but I've decided not to post questions/answers any more. I'll restrict to commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As predicted in the comments, your macro is adding a lot of spaces.

```
\providecommand*{\cvitem}[4][]{
    \ifstrequal{#3}{-}{#2 – present}{
            \ifstrequal{#2}{#3}{#2}{
                #2 – #3
            }
    } & \parbox[t]{12.3cm}{ \raggedright
                \textbf{#4} 
                    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{  \\ #1 } % Only output second line if optional parameter given
            \\[0.5cm] }  \\
}
```

adds many space tokens, it needs to be

```
\providecommand*{\cvitem}[4][]{%
    \ifstrequal{#3}{-}{#2 – present}{%
            \ifstrequal{#2}{#3}{#2}{%
                #2 – #3%
            }%
    } & \parbox[t]{12.3cm}{\raggedright
                \textbf{#4}%
                    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{\\ #1}% Only output second line if optional parameter given
            \\[0.5cm]}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, solved the problem perfectly! And thank you all for being patient with me ;)